# How To insert Array to MySQL with Volley Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, android-volley

I have some problem, I searched on google and stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything that would answer my problem.

My case is that I can't save Array list into my database.

[I have Multiple selection, and a put it to RecycleView like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ9ji.png)
I get the position and value from the `Recyleview`, then put into an array, and next I put each of them into a HashMap, save it successfull, but all data is saved with duplicate values (same with Array Length)

[This is data from my DB, is duplicated saved, but i have select two different item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myp7X.png)

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jPesan = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean pesan = jPesan.names().get(1).equals("success");
                        if (pesan == true){
                            PD.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Data Personil Terlibat Berhasil di Simpan",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(pesan == false){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Terjadi Kesalahan",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            PD.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Terjadi Kesalahan Jaringan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            // HERE I PUT ARRAY TO HASMAP

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrPers.length; i++){
                params.put("nrp", arrPers[i]);
                params.put("id-jadwal", idJadwal);
            }

            return params;


        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(postRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send arrays by specifying the key:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrPers.length; i++){
    params.put("nrp["+i+"]", arrPers[i]);//specify the key of the array you post
    params.put("id-jadwal", idJadwal);
}
```

In your PHP you should have somthing like:

```
var_dump($_POST['nrp']);// array('1110112','1110113'....);

foreach($_POST['nrp'] as $option) { //just as an example
    //insert each element in db ($option and user id)
}
```